# Overriding the default User-Agent header for Exchange request

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, user-agent

I am sending a request to EWS as below:

```
var service = new ExchangeService(exchangeVersion)
                                  {
                                      KeepAlive = true,
                                      Url = new Uri("some autodiscovery url"),
                                      Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password),
                                      UserAgent = "myClient"
                                  };

var subscription = service.SubscribeToPushNotifications(
                                    new[] { inboxFolderFoldeID },
                                    new Uri("some post back url"),
                                    15,
                                    null,
                                    EventType.NewMail,
                                    EventType.Created,
                                    EventType.Deleted,
                                    EventType.Modified,
                                    EventType.Moved,
                                    EventType.Copied);
```

But, it would result into a request having the User-Agent header as `myClient (ExchangeServicesClient/15.00.0913.015)` where the rest of the string is coming from the EWS library where it is using this default value. Is there a way to remove the default part of the header and just have it as `myClient`?

Edit: I can see that EWS library seems to be simply prefixing the value passed in the request: https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api/blob/master/Core/ExchangeServiceBase.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to recompile the library from GitHub as the scope of the existing variables won't allow you to change them any other way. eg all you need to do is modify UserAgent

```
    public string UserAgent
    {
        get { return this.userAgent; }
        set { this.userAgent = value + " (" + ExchangeService.defaultUserAgent + ")"; }
    }
```

and get rid of the prefix then when you set the property on the ExchangeService class it will only be your custom value.

Comment: yeah, seems the only way to achieve that.